# Get active Excel worksheet name/index number using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

I am trying to open an Excel file using Powershell, and then get the name (or index number) of the active worksheet.

(The end goal is to print/export the active worksheet as a PDF.)

```
$ExcelFileName = 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\graph.xlsx'
# creates path to excel file
$Excel = New-Object -COMObject Excel.Application
# creates an excel com object
$Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFileName)
# opens the workbook file
$WorkSheetName = $excel.WorksheetView.Sheet
# supposedly returns the name of the active work sheet
$WorkSheetObject = $excel.Workbooks.Item($WorkSheetName)
# error happens here when trying to create worksheet object
$WorkSheetObject.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,[ref]$NewFileName)
# this code would export worksheet to pdf
```

This code produces an error (see below). The Workbooks.Item method seems to require the sheet name as a string or integer, which WorksheetView.Sheet is not returning. Maybe.

```
Invalid Index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
At line:9 char:5
+     $WorkSheetObject = $excel.Workbooks.Item($WorkSheetName))
```

I've also tried using these lines of code to return the active sheet name or index number, but I get the same error when I pass them as the $WorkSheetName (see below).

```
$ActiveSheet = $excel.Workbook.ActiveSheet
$WorkSheetName = $ActiveSheet.name
$WorkSheetObject = $excel.Workbooks.Item($WorkSheetName)
```

I haven't found anything else to answer this in the Microsoft docs or on forums, so thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Q&D (quick and dirty).  Using Excel natively, open one of your XLS files. Launch the macro recorder. Step thru what you are trying. Stop the macro recorder. Review the VBA code. Convert for the PowerShell use case.

Comment: An instance of Excel can have multiple files open - each file is called a Work**book**. Each Workbook can have many Work**sheets**. Your code is trying to find a Work**book** with the same name as the active Work**sheet**… ```$WorkSheetObject = $excel.Workbooks.Item($WorkSheetName)```.

Comment: Tons of examples of the scenario all over the web. ['Powershell get active worksheet name'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+get+active+worksheet+name%27&t=h_&ia=web) --- For example: 
[Solved: Powershell - Retrieving Excel Sheet Name](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-powershell-retrieving-excel-sheet-name.911029) --
[Even Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+get+active+worksheet+name), showing this kind of thing. Sure they are showing VBA, but converting that ot PS is faily straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mine for what you are after if you do not know the full namespace already. For Example:

```
$ExcelFileName = 'D:\temp\Test.xlsx'
$ExcelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFileName)

# Results
<#
...
ActiveChart                      :
ActiveSheet                      : System.__ComObject
...
#>


 $ExcelApp.Work
# Results
<#
Workbooks                          WorkbookAddinInstall               WorkbookAfterXmlImport             WorkbookBeforeXmlExport            WorkbookNewChart                   WorkbookPivotTableOpenConnection
WorksheetFunction                  WorkbookAddinUninstall             WorkbookBeforeClose                WorkbookBeforeXmlImport            WorkbookNewSheet                   WorkbookRowsetComplete
Worksheets                         WorkbookAfterSave                  WorkbookBeforePrint                WorkbookDeactivate                 WorkbookOpen                       WorkbookSync
WorkbookActivate                   WorkbookAfterXmlExport             WorkbookBeforeSave                 WorkbookModelChange                WorkbookPivotTableCloseConnection

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks Workbooks {get;}
#>

<#
Note that there is no property called '$ExcelApp.WorksheetView.Sheet' at this level of the Excel COM.
So all the remaining code does not matter.

However, there is, 
#>

$ExcelApp.Worksheets
# Results
<#
Worksheets
#>

# So, 
$ExcelApp.Active
<#
ActiveCell                 ActiveDialog               ActiveMenuBar              ActiveProtectedViewWindow  ActiveWindow               ActivateMicrosoftApp
ActiveChart                ActiveEncryptionSession    ActivePrinter              ActiveSheet                ActiveWorkbook

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ActiveCell {get;}
#>

# Now, digging further
$ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.
# Results
<#
_AutoFilter                        EnableFormatConditionsCalculation  Previous                           __PrintOut                         Drawings                           PrintOut
_CodeName                          EnableOutlining                    PrintedCommentPages                __SaveAs                           DropDowns                          PrintPreview
_DisplayRightToLeft                EnablePivotTable                   ProtectContents                    _CheckSpelling                     Equals                             Protect
_Sort                              EnableSelection                    ProtectDrawingObjects              _Evaluate                          Evaluate                           Rectangles
Application                        FilterMode                         Protection                         _ExportAsFixedFormat               ExportAsFixedFormat                ResetAllPageBreaks
AutoFilter                         HPageBreaks                        ProtectionMode                     _PasteSpecial                      GetHashCode                        SaveAs
AutoFilterMode                     Hyperlinks                         ProtectScenarios                   _PrintOut                          GetLifetimeService                 Scenarios
Cells                              Index                              QueryTables                        _Protect                           GetType                            ScrollBars
CircularReference                  ListObjects                        Rows                               _SaveAs                            GroupBoxes                         Select
CodeName                           MailEnvelope                       Scripts                            Activate                           GroupObjects                       SetBackgroundPicture
Columns                            Name                               ScrollArea                         Arcs                               InitializeLifetimeService          ShowAllData
Comments                           NamedSheetViews                    Shapes                             Buttons                            Labels                             ShowDataForm
CommentsThreaded                   Names                              SmartTags                          Calculate                          Lines                              Spinners
ConsolidationFunction              Next                               Sort                               ChartObjects                       ListBoxes                          TextBoxes
ConsolidationOptions               OnCalculate                        StandardHeight                     CheckBoxes                         Move                               ToString
ConsolidationSources               OnData                             StandardWidth                      CheckSpelling                      OLEObjects                         Unprotect
Creator                            OnDoubleClick                      Tab                                CircleInvalid                      OptionButtons                      XmlDataQuery
CustomProperties                   OnEntry                            TransitionExpEval                  ClearArrows                        Ovals                              XmlMapQuery
DisplayAutomaticPageBreaks         OnSheetActivate                    TransitionFormEntry                ClearCircles                       Paste                              Range
DisplayPageBreaks                  OnSheetDeactivate                  Type                               Copy                               PasteSpecial
DisplayRightToLeft                 Outline                            UsedRange                          CreateObjRef                       Pictures
EnableAutoFilter                   PageSetup                          Visible                            Delete                             PivotTables
EnableCalculation                  Parent                             VPageBreaks                        DrawingObjects                     PivotTableWizard

AutoFilter _AutoFilter () {get}
#>
```

Comment: This was hugely helpful to me. Thank you. Once I opened the file I was able to mine (or check the methods and properties of each object) in PowerShell this way: $Excel | get-member, $Excel.ActiveSheet | get-member. My original code looks pretty silly to me now, but I was able to find what I needed.

Comment: No worries. We've all been there in our careers at one point or another and bound to happen to us later. Well, in most respects.  ***;-}***  --- My sample was just stepping into the object and member reference via in-line help, the normal hotkey ***crtl+spacebar***, GM is just as useful and used regularly.

Comment: Also useful to know, thank you.